# Dangerous for loop idiom?

Tags: r

taking an example from [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html)

```
xc <- split(x, ind)
yc <- split(y, ind)
for (i in 1:length(yc)) {
    plot(xc[[i]], yc[[i]])
    abline(lsfit(xc[[i]], yc[[i]]))
}
```

It seems that `for(i in 1:length(yc)) { ...` is an idiom for iterating over a list or vector in the case where you need a handle on the current index. This however breaks in the case of an empty list since `1:0` is not an empty vector. What is the idiom I should use for iterating over list/vector indices when you aren't guaranteed a non-empty list? I'm thinking `if(length(yc)) for(i in 1:length(yc)) { ...` but is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for `seq_along`.

```
> seq_along(as.list(1:2))
[1] 1 2
> seq_along(list())
integer(0)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `seq_along`:

```
for(i in seq_along(yc)) {...}
```

I'm pretty sure this bypasses the problem *and* should be a tiny bit faster.

Answer (score 4):

This question is covered on page 75 of 'The R Inferno': http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

It tells you a few other ways to get your loop wrong as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You'll find the R inferno is held in high regard here.  It's a great resource, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who happens to stumble upon this -- if you want an index vector based on possibly zero length, rather than another vector, you can safely use `seq(1, length.out = L)`, where L can be any non-negative integer. That will give you `integer(0)` if `L == 0`, and `1:L` otherwise.

Of course the other solutions given here are more concise if `L == length(something)`, but I had a problem where that wasn't the case, so I thought I'd write it down for progeny.

Also `seq(1, length.out = L)` can be abbreviated as `seq_len(L)`, which according to `?seq` is faster.